# Git Changing User

Tags: git, github

I first installed Git with the ID ID-A when I installed Git.
And I uploaded the ReadMe.md file to Repo.

But now I want to use ID-B ID instead of ID-A.
So I'll show you what I did.

```bash
git config --global user.name "ID-B"
git config --global user.email ID-B@domain.com
rm -rf .git

git config user.name  # ID-B
git config user.email # ID-B@domain.com

git init
git add test.rtf
git commit -m "test commit"

git remote add origin https://github.com/ID-B/test.git
git push -u origin master  
# Remote: Permission to ID-B / test.git denied to ID-A.
# Fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ID-B/test.git/': 
# The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I think I changed the ID from ID-A to ID-B, but it does not change somewhere, so when I try to connect with ID-B, it seems to fail.

So I tried to reinstall the command with the following command.

```
rm -rf / usr / local / git
```

I've also run the command, but only the phrase Permission denied.
How can I change this?

Thank you

Comment: Is this a shared repository ? Have you tried using ssh instead of https? Have you set your ssh keys correctly ? Is that user set as a collaborator on that repo?

Comment: Git never does its own authentication so the Git setting of `user.name` means nothing here. Instead, Git asks some sort of helper—the details vary from one OS to another; there are different helpers on Windows, OSX, and Linux for instance—to send user-name-and-password for `https` connections. It is this helper, whichever one it is, that you must adjust.